# Error: Could not find or load main class org.jruby.Main

Tags: ruby, jruby

When i install ruby gems it shows error as

`Error: Could not find or load main class org.jruby.Main`

I didnt find any proper installation steps for jruby.

Please help me with this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this error show up while you are installing the gems? Post the complete transscript - i.e. the commands you entered, and the complete output.

Comment: thanks..i have removed this error by completely removing all the hidden files that will be installed in Jruby installation and again i tried to install the latest version..it didnt showed up any error..running successfully

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Below is what I did to resolve it:

Step 1: Added JRUBY_HOME environment variable with installation directory as value(**without bin folder**). My path was C:\Tools\jruby-1.7.21. **See bin folder isn't included**.

Step 2: Added bin folder path to PATH environment variable, i.e. edit PATH and append C:\Tools\jruby-1.7.21\bin; **Here bin folder is included.**